# Update values in table: sql - APSX

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, sql-update

I have the following code:

**updated**

```
 try
    {
        ArticleId = Request.QueryString["ArticleId"].ToString();
        NewArticleTitle = Request.Form["ArticleTitle"].ToString();
        NewArticleDate = Request.Form["ArticleDate"].ToString();
        NewArticleBody = Request.Form["ArticleBody"].ToString();


        string dpath = Server.MapPath(@"App_Data") + "/MySite.mdb";
        string connectionstring = @"Data source='" + dpath + "';Provider='Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0';";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring);
        string QuaryString = String.Format("update tblarticles set articletitle='{0}', articlebody='{1}', postdate='{2}'  where articleid={3}", NewArticleTitle, NewArticleBody, NewArticleDate, ArticleId);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(QuaryString, con);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "tbl");
        con.Close();
        Response.Redirect("ArticlesTable.aspx");
    }
        catch { }
```

The ArticleId is an AUTO INCREMENT (in number type) 
When it  got to this line  `da.Fill(ds, "tbl");` the program coutinue to the catch.
My quastion is how can I prevent it so the table will be really update ?
Wish for help, thanks!

Comment: You may want to catch the exception (for instance, `catch (Exception ex) { Response.Write(ex.Message); }`) to see what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `ArticleId` is Numeric so you need to replace this:

```
where ArticleId='{3}'
```

With this:

```
where ArticleId={3}
```

So your where clause should look like:

```
"update tblArticles set ArticleTitle='{0}', ArticleBody='{1}',PostDate='{2}'  where ArticleId={3}"
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed it but I still get the same problem why?

Comment: because the answer Yaqub provided is incorrect.. why would you need to have single quotes for Params when the text is already wrapped in double qoutes.. this answer is not correct

Comment: @DJKRAZE: it will result ------
update tblarticles set articletitle='someValue', articlebody='someValue', postdate='someValue' where articleid = 1

So whats wrong?

Comment: this is what he needs for starters 
`String.Format("update tblarticles set articletitle='{0}', articlebody= {1}, postdate= {2}  where articleid={3}", NewArticleTitle, NewArticleBody, NewArticleDate, ArticleId);` also why is he filling a DataSet after running a Delete Query..? doesn't look normal he should do that in to different steps if I am understanding what he's trying to do..also he should refactor the SQL Insert to use Parameter.AddWithValue method to run that Insert Query..

Comment: Your provided solution will results:

update tblarticles set articletitle='title', articlebody= articlebosy, postdate=2012-01-13 where articleid = 1

---- Are you sure that it WILL WORK?

Answer (score 1):

If the `ArticleId` is of data type numeric, then you have to remove the quotes around it. Instead of:

```
 where ArticleId='{3}'
```

Try this:

```
 where ArticleId = {3}
```

But, you shouldn't do that this way. Try to use the prepared statements, or parametrized queries instead of the `String.Format`.

Comment: Thank you, I changed it to   "where ArticleId = {3}" but I still get the same problem why?

Comment: @NaveTseva Can you please post the exception you got? also try to print the query before you execute it and test it directly.

Comment: There is no any error, the poblem is that it stack in this line  "da.Fill(ds, "tbl");" and cotinue to the "catch"

Comment: Do you know why is it stack in this line? "da.Fill(ds, "tbl");"

Comment: @NaveTseva Why do you use `da.Fill`? There is no data to fill coming from an `UPDATE` query, you should use `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead

Answer (score 0):

Argument insertion is an bad idea. It is potentially harmful code opened for `sql injection`. Use Parameters instead of argument insertion. Sql parameters is useful for fast finding errors, too. Because parametes strongly typed and you can't pass string as argument for numeric parameter.